# in MS ACCESS, is it possible to do: DoCmd.OpenForm "Dlookup...."?

Tags: ms-access, vba

MS Access 2013
I have a tblUser table with following data (UserName / Password / StartForm)
I have a login system in place where user puts in form field called txtLogin his UserName.

After UserName and Password matches, I need to open a specific form for each user (depending on his function in the company).
I have this code in place but can't figure out the problem.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm DLookup("StartForm", "tblUser","[UserName]='" & txtLogin & "';")
```

I am only starting programming and I want to learn, not copy/paste code, so I appreciate very much if you can give me a simple explanation.

Thank you

Comment: hello @HansUp. Yes.. I figured an answer. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter to [`DoCmd.OpenForm`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845.aspx) is the form name. To open the form to a specific parameter you need to use the 
4th parameter which is the `WhereCondition`.

The `Dlookup` function is not necessary here. It is used to return a single column from a single record where the sourced column is the first parameter and the source table is the second parameter. It knows what record to grab by the search criteria, the third parameter.

The way you have this set up you are asking `DoCmd.OpenForm` to open a form by the name of `[the result of your DLookup call]` with no filter applied.

What you want is more like this

```
DoCmd.OpenForm NameOfYourUserForm, acNormal, , "[UserName]='" & txtLogin & "'"
```

Comment: Hello. your answer was instructive and I appreciate. I ended up using other method though. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem as following.
I created a variable for the form I want to call (nomeForm) and I used Dlookup to find appropriate form to each user.

Thank you

```
Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()

     Dim rst As Recordset
     Dim nomeUsuario As String

    If IsNull(txtLogin) Or IsNull(txtSenha) Then
    MsgBox "Preencha o login e senha"
    Exit Sub
    End If

    nomeUsuario = txtLogin

    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE UserName = '" & txtLogin & "' AND Password = '" & txtSenha & "';")

    If rst.RecordCount = 1 Then

    bcansafelyclose = True
    DoCmd.Close

    Dim nomeForm As String
    nomeForm = DLookup("Start", "tblUser", "UserName = '" & nomeUsuario & "'")

    DoCmd.OpenForm nomeForm

    Else

    MsgBox "Login ou senha incorretos"
    bcansafelyclose = False

    End If

    rst.Close

    End Sub
```